# Visualstudio 2010 vertical axis interval

Tags: visual-studio-2010, reporting-services, graph

This graph is to show the vertical axis with 1 million intervals,
not 2 million.
How exactly can I change that in VisualStudio2010 ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right-click the vertical axis, click `Vertical Axis Properties...` and set the `Interval` to `1000000`

Comment: This question is on topic because it was produced by codes in the first place. It does not ask for a recommendation, nor for books. It is simply dealing with a topic that is a direct derivative of a sequence of codes. Therefore, it is - in my view - on topic.